# Visual Studio 2015 and remote debugger - Cannot connect to a service process that is starting

Tags: visual-studio, remote-debugging, visual-studio-2015

When using Visual Studio 2015 and its x64, 2015 version remote debugger - I can't connect to a service process that is starting. It's not an issue connecting to a process that is running.

Connecting to a service while it is starting is useful because determining why a service is not successfully starting is not easy unless attached with a debugger.

I am sure this was working with VS 2012, has anyone else noted this?

Note connecting to a service that has started works just fine.